# Finding the longest word in a string is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm supposed to find the longest word in a string, this is the code I've come up with so far. Unfortunately, this seems not to be working, and my question is why?

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) { 
  str.split("");
  let longest = 1;
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if (str[i].length > longest){
       longest = str[i].length;
    }
  }
  return longest;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error? Getting the wrong value? etc.

Comment: You should attempt some debugging. You could insert some console.log statements into your code to try to find when the functionality deviates from what you expect. It also looks like this code is going to return the length of the longest string. Is that what you want?

Comment: i guess you suppose to do `str=str.split(" ");`

Comment: Yes, I want the result to be a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I undestood correctly, there are two main issues:

**1)** You are not storing the result of [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) anywhere.

**2)** If you need to split the distinct words, you will need to split by `space`

I will also start with `longest = 0` instead of `1`

## Example:

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str)
{ 
    str = str.split(" ");
    let longest = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i].length > longest)
            longest = str[i].length;
    }

    return longest;
}

console.log(findLongestWordLength("Hello World"));
console.log(findLongestWordLength(""));
console.log(findLongestWordLength("123 1234567 12345"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Alternatively, you can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to `map` every word to his length, and then `spread` this array of lengths on [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to get the desired result:

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str)
{
    let wordLengths = str.split(" ").map(word => word.length);
    return Math.max(...wordLengths);
}

console.log(findLongestWordLength("Hello World"));
console.log(findLongestWordLength(""));
console.log(findLongestWordLength("123 1234567 12345"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is second line need change to   `str = str.split(" ");` because Strings are immutable they cannot change, need reassign it.

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) { 
  str = str.split(" ");
  let longest = 1;
  console.log(str);
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if (str[i].length > longest){
       longest = str[i].length;
    }
  }
  return longest;
}

var result = findLongestWordLength("Joan Ala Valeron")
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the string by `" "`. Then iterate through the words and return the biggest one's length.

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  const words = str.split(" ");
  return words.reduce(
    (max, word) => (word.length > max ? word.length : max),
    0
  );
}

console.log(findLongestWordLength("hello world"));
```

This solution is shorter and cleaner because of using `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this code.

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split(' ');
  var longest = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++){
    if(strSplit[i].length > longest){
    longest = strSplit[i].length;
     }
  }
  return longest;
}
findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Comment: Answers like _"You can try this code."_ are not considered good answers even if the code is correct. You should explain what is problem in OP's try and then tell how you are going to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) { 
  var otherStr = str.split(" ");
  let longest = 0;
  for(let i = 1; i < otherStr.length; i++){
    if (otherStr[i].length > otherStr[longest].length){
       longest = i;
    }
  }
  return otherStr[longest];
}

findLongestWordLength("This is the String Data")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because you are traversing through each character in the string whose length is 1. You are not comparing the length of the words.

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
    let words = str.split(" ");  // Delemiter to separate words from sentence is space
    let longest = 1;
    for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    if (words[i].length > longest){
       longest = words[i].length;
    }
  }
  return longest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function spacer(m)
{
  var space = "";
  for(var inst = 0; inst < m;inst++)
    space += "\n";
  console.log(space);
}

function findLongestWordLength(str) {

  //Checking that what you are sending is a string...
  if(typeof str !== "string")
    throw "This function requires you to pass in a string...";

  //Ghetto Class...lol
  function CreateWord(word)
  {
      this.word = word;
      this.length = word.length;
  }

  // Getting all the words...but taking out the words that are ""
  var AllWords = str.split(" ").filter(word => word != ""),

    // This is how many words you have that are not ""
    wordCount = AllWords.length,

    // Defaulting the longest word to the first word...
    longest = new CreateWord(AllWords[0]);

    // if we only have one, we return the one word...
    if(wordCount === 1)
        return longest;

  for(let i = 0; i < wordCount; i++){
    if (AllWords[i].length > longest.length){
       longest = new CreateWord(AllWords[i]);
    }
  }
  return longest;
}

//Simple Test...
var Implementation = findLongestWordLength("ONE TWO THREE FOUR  TESTINGLONGWORD");
console.log(Implementation);
console.log(`Word: ${Implementation.word}`);
console.log(`Length: ${Implementation.length}`);

spacer(3);

//Single word...
var Implementation2 = findLongestWordLength("Only-One-Word");
console.log(Implementation2);
console.log(`Word: ${Implementation2.word}`);
console.log(`Length: ${Implementation2.length}`);

spacer(3);

//Exception...because I dont want want you to misUse this function....
var Implementation3 = findLongestWordLength(null);
console.log(Implementation3);
console.log(`Word: ${Implementation3.word}`);
console.log(`Length: ${Implementation3.length}`);
```